# message success in ajax post

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a code that sends a series of posts at the time of clicking a button, several posts are sent at the same time, for each post I show a success message (alert). Is there a way to limit the success messages to 1 ?, for example if 4 posts are sent, that only an alert is sent to the HTML page, is there a way to do this?

**This is my code:**

```
$('#save').on('click', function () {

        $(".draggable").each(function () {
            var elem = $(this),
                id = elem.attr('id'),
                pos = elem.position(),
                left = pos.left,
                top = pos.top;

            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "{% url 'update-positions-device' %}",
                headers: {'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
                data: {idd: id, left: left, top: top},
                success: function (response) {
                    alert("Sending data positions");
                },
                complete: function () {
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, thrownError) {
                    alert("The data could not be sent");
                }
            })

        })

    })
```

Comment: You can use `$.when()` to wait for all the promises to finish.  However, from a user experience point of view, `alert()` is a terrible user experience now days.  You should in most cases use a modal of some sort instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am trying to use it this way and it doesn't work:
`success: function (response) {$ .when (di ()) .done (function () {alert ("Sending data positions");})},` do you know when the $ .when might apply?

Comment: You cannot use the when inside the success, as it expectes to be given all the promises/deferred elements that the $.ajax method creates.  Take a look at the https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when docs